# Using Gnome-Schedule to run shell script that opens Chromium browser

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian 8.0. I have a shell script that triggers a Chromium Browser to open and go to a specified URL that changes every day. The shell script works when executed from the terminal. How would I get this to work through Gnome Schedule's GUI? I would like this to trigger everyday at a specified time. I've tried setting the command to `/home/pi/test.sh`, `sh /home/pi/test.sh`. I read something about needing to specify the display output since I'm running Gnome Schedule from root which isn't the current user logged in. So for that I tried `export DISPLAY=:0 && /home/pi/test.sh`. Is this going to be possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more of a Linux question than a programming question. Suggest you delete this and ask on https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: `export DISPLAY=:0.0` is what I believe might work

Comment: @HarveyFletcher putting that at the top of my shell script worked!

Comment: @A.Collins I have added this as an answer please accept as the solution

Answer (score 0):

If you put

`export DISPLAY=:0.0` at the top of your script rather than `export DISPLAY=:0`, this should work.